# Cannot connect to the internet in a Blackberry 6 simulator in windows machine

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I am not able to connect through a blackberry 6 simulator.But blackberry 5 simulator connects to the internet properly.I have updated my proxy settings in `rimpublic.property` file of the MDS simulator.One strange thing i observed is with BB 6 simulator,I can access files in the local webserver in my machine by giving the IP,but cannot access any external website lets say google.com.With BB 5 simulator,it is the other way around-can access internet but not local webserver.

Anything else I need to do make this work?.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just check another time whether the MDS enabled for the simulator. Another try is just clean the simulator. Go to this path C:\Eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack6.0.0_6.0.0.30\components\simulator\
and search for Clean.bat file and double click on it and wait till it gets completed. Make sure that your simulator is closed during this process. once its completed, check your simulator.

Comment: Thanks for answering.How to check if MDS is enabled?.But I think MDS is enabled because if it is not enabled I would not have been able to access localhost in BB 6 and internet in BB 5.Right?.I have already tried running clean.bat.But no use.

Comment: To enable the MDS go to Run --> Run Configurations --> Simulator --> check whether "Launch Mobile Data System Connection Service (MDS-CS) with simulator" is ticked. If its not ticked means tick it and apply the changes and run the simulator again and try.